# Why does calling ffmpeg from python block?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I tried 3 methods to call ffmpeg from python, but it always blocks and doesn't return any result.

However, if I execute it from shell, it works.

For eg:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y  -i /tmp/uploadedfiles/movie8_15_10s.mpg -ar 1600 -ac 1  /tmp/uploadedfiles/movie8_15_10s.mpg.wav
```

this works.

However,

```
 ffmpeg_command = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y  -i test.wav testout.wav" 
 f_ffmpeg=os.popen(ffmpeg_command);
```

This makes the python hang.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instead of `os.popen`.

In particular, to get same behaviour, you can run the process through a shell with `shell=True` and gather the output from `stdout` and `stderr` as follows:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = p.communicate()[0]
```

where `command` is the same command line you would write in a shell.

Answer (score 1):

(This is not a direct answer to your question) but if you have multiple files to convert you can try something like this: (put your script.py in the same folder)

```
import os
import subprocess

fileList = os.listdir("path")

for name in fileList:
  command = 'ffmpeg -i' + ' ' + str(name) +' '+'-f mp3'+' '+ str(name)+'.mp3'
  p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  output = p.communicate()[0]
```

**Please NOTE the variable COMMAND**

Comment: Can this be modified to answer the question?