# avoiding running of FFmpeg on terminal/cmd

Tags: python, ffmpeg, command-line

I'm using FFmpeg for a small project so I built a GUI basic application for video editing
here is the image
[image]

Everything is working fine but I just want to avoid opening the terminal for the FFmpeg process the reason the terminal is opening is because

```
I used os.system("FFmpeg command here")
```

so is there a way to import FFmpeg completely and avoid using terminal and run in code 
if u have any idea please suggest and let me know 
for gui i used PYQT5 and python to code
Thank you

Tried using subprogram but didn't work (worked for normal commands but not for ffmpeg)
I need the output to print also to store in a python variable
Please check the image for more info

[image]

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Use os.system to run terminal commands from python.

Comment: yes but I want to run commands that work on the terminal but I want to run in code only rather than running on the terminal
heard of using subprocess but for FFmpeg isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 options to solve this:

1. Running the ffmpeg command without console window. You can achieve this by using subprocess.run with the CREATE_NO_WINDOW flag, as:

```python
    import subprocess
    
    subprocess.run(["path/to/ffmpeg", "arg1", "arg2"],
    creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```

*Note that the CREATE_NO_WINDOW flag is only available since Python 3.7*

2. Using a Python wrapper for libffmpeg see for example: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python with many examples.

Comment: I did try it but nothing is being printed were as normal commands are working fine with subprocess codes
just updated the query too
Thank you

Comment: Chances are that if something is wrong, ffmpeg will print it on stderr, not stdout, so add `print(p1.stderr.decode())` as well, hopefully you will see more.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try appending '-hide_banner -loglevel warning' to your command?

```
os.system("FFmpeg command here -hide_banner -loglevel warning")
```

You can always redirect to /dev/null

```
os.system('FFmpeg command here 2> /dev/null')
```

Comment: but I do want the data which is being printed on cmd please to recheck the post tried using subprocess but didn't work for ffmpeg